# Is there a Running Object Table in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

In C# I had do create my own dynamic memory management. For that reason I have created a static memory manager and a MappableObject. All object that should be dynamic mappable and unmappable from and to the harddisk implement this interface.

This memory management is only done for these large objects that have the ability to unmap/map the data from the harddisk. All other things use of course the regular GC.

Everytime a MappableObject is allocated it asks for memory. If no memory is available that the MemoryManager unmaps some data dynamically to the harddisk to get more memory to make it possible to allocate a new MappableObject.

A problem in my case is that I can have more than 100.000 MappableObject instances (scattered over a few files ~ 10-20 files) and everytime I have to run through a list of all objects if I need to unmap some data. Is there a way to get all allocated objects that are created in my current instance?

In fact I don't know what's easier to keep my own list or to run through the objects (if possible)? How would you solve such things?

**Update**

The reason is that I have a large amount of data. About 100GB of data that I need to keep during my run. Therefore I need the references on the data, and so the GC is not able to clean the memory. In fact C# manages the memory pretty well, but in such memory exhausting applications the GC gets really bad. Of course I tried to use the MemoryFailPoint, but this slows down my allocations tremendously and does not give correct results for whatever reason. I have also tried MemoryMappedFiles, but since I have to access the data randomly it doesn't help. Also MemoryMappedFiles only allow to have ~5000 file handles (on my system) and this is not enough.

Comment: isn't this what the garbage collector is for?  does the .net api even support memory management?

Comment: Can you provide some context about why you need to do this?  C# manages its own memory pretty well.  Is there a reason you need to do something on top of that?

Comment: Can you give some background information on why you had to do that?

Comment: My guess is that he has too much stuff to fit into memory so needs a way to store things on disk when needed so they can be taken out of memory.

Comment: Yes, Rangoric that's the reason. I had a few questions here on StackOverflow to the same topic with different approaches. But currently it seems to me that I have to use Unmanaged memory to keep better track of what I'm doing.

Comment: @msedi I have added your comment to your question. Please delete you comment.

Comment: These kind of data set sizes are well beyond what's practical.  If a dbase engine cannot give you the perf you need then you need to talk to IBM and kick the tires on some Big Iron.

Comment: Hi Hans, the problem is that it has nothing to do with datasets from a database. This data is mostly 2D pixel data from a set of images or measurement data from a CT scanner. The regular datasizes of such data is about 10GB, but during a few steps there is several intermediate data created. Some of this data can be deleted (what I do) and some of the data is necessary during some loop. At least I always clean up everything I don't need anymore. In fact I expected a little bit more out of C# to get more information of memory allocations from the GC.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a ROT (Running Object Table) in .Net? The short answer is no.

You would have to maintain this information yourself.

Given your question update, could you not store your data in a database and use some sort of in-memory cache (perhaps with weak references or MFU, etc) to try and keep hot data close to you?

Comment: Hi chibacity. I have tried the WeakReference, but on 32bit systems I have experienced that the reference gets lost too early. I have tried this with a very small dataset and in fact on a 2GB system I allocated 3 objects and after allocating the 4th the first was gone. I even don't which bottleneck is produced by using so many WeakReferences?

Comment: @msedi That fact that the GC runs after you add a 4th object is *very* unexpected. The GC should only run when it believes there is memory pressure, or it is called directly. How big are these objects approximately?

Comment: Normally the datasizes are approx. 512x512x4 1MB. At least this also seemed very odd to me, but I have tested this many times and this was my result. Maybe the GC has changed since NET 3.0, where I did the tests. I have to check again.

Comment: @msedi This question is devolving into lots of other questions. It really needs to be broken up into more targeted chunks.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It somehow needs more discussion on the general framework of what I want to do and what the problems are. Do you have a good idea where I place such a larger discussion?

Comment: @msedi I would suggest breaking it up into smaller problems you have had. I find it's better to ask these along the way, instead of waiting till the end.

Answer (score 0):

This is an obvious case for a classic cache.  Your data is stored in a database or indexed flat file while you maintain a much smaller number of entries in RAM.

To implement a cache for your program I would create a class that implements IDictionary.  Reserve a certain amount of slots in your cache, say a number of elements that would cause about 100 MB of RAM to be allocated; make this cache size an adjustable parameter.

When you override this[], if the object requested is in the cache, return it.  If the object requested is not in the cache, remove the least recently used cached value, add the requested value as the most recently used value, and return it.  Functions like Remove() and Add() not only adjust the memory cache, but also manipulate the underlying database or flat file on disk.

While it's true that your program might hold some references to objects you removed from the cache, if so, your program is still using them.  Garbage collection will clean them up as needed.

Caches like this are easier to implement in C# because of its strong OOP features and safety.

Comment: Hi AresAvater, the problem is that I don't have only one file - I have more. As explained to Hans Passant, I have pixel volume data and projection data from a CT scanner. The data is reconstructed using CUDA and the result are stored in managed memory which works quite well unless enough memory is available. In fact I have currently an adjustable parameter, but nevertheless the GC informations about how much memory is available and how much not is not very stable. On one run of the app at the end it could happen that I have only 4GB(of 32GB) left, although every object has been cleaned.

Comment: @msedi, each type of data should have its own cache.  In fact, you could easily write a generic Cache class and derive classes for each data type overriding the parts that manipulate your underlying databases.

Comment: @AresAvater: In fact this is somehow the things I'm currently doing. The only problem is that the information the GC gives is not very realiable.

Comment: There is no reason you should need anything from the GC.